# Why didn't my Destiny progress on PS4 transfer back to PS3?

Tags: ps3, destiny

I had Destiny for PS3. Then I switched to PS4 for a little while. Now I'm back on PS3 and none of my data from PS4 saved. My PlayStation Plus membership expired already; could that be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

No, expired PS Plus is not the problem.

Starting on August 16, 2016, Bungie has ended updates for the PS3 and Xbox 360 versions of Destiny (or "legacy consoles" as they call them). This also means that your progress between the two are split - anything you've done with Destiny on your PS4 since then will not be reflected on your characters on PS3 (and vice versa).

[Bungie's Help website](https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Troubleshoot?oid=44808) has more information on what exactly has changed for legacy consoles now that the two platforms are split.